# Finding the probability of two points.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Assume I have two points A, and B, in $R^2$ where the measurement of $B$, $B'$, has some noise $\sigma$, and A is known with certainty. The noise is incorporated by using a Gaussian:

$B'_x$ = Gaussian($B_x$, $\sigma$)

$B'_y$ = Gaussian($B_y$, $\sigma$)

The noise is constant.

How do I calculate the error of $B'$ relative to A?

I initially thought that I could calculate a Gaussian as the product of the Gaussians across x and y factoring the noise in as the variance. For example

```
A = [0,1]
B= [10, 2]

error = 1
for l in length(A):
    err = B[l] - A[l]
    error = error * (exp( -(err ** 2) / (N ** 2) / 2.0) /  
                     sqrt( N ** 2))
```

However, I am not sure this correct. And the reason I am not sure this is correct is that I notice that for many A's with respect to $B'$, the error is not normalised.

Comment: what does "probability of the measurement" mean? Are you asking about its distribution? How exactly is the noise added to $B$? What is the distribution of the noise? Are the points in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: I've updated the question, thanks Slug!

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying $B = b + N$ where $b$ is the actual point and $N$ is a noise such that $N \sim \mathcal N (\mu, \sigma)$, or are you saying $B$ is itself a Normal random variable with $N$ as standard deviation?

Comment: also – are both coordinates of the measurement of $B$ noisy or only the first one? If both, are you assuming a bivariate Normal distribution?

Comment: @SlugPue my apologies, I've made some corrections, I hope I have made more sense. If not, could we use the chat?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the mean of A, $a=\mathbb{E}A$ , and having already b=B, then apply the distance $\mathbb{E}d(A,B)=d(a,b)$.

If you take the mean after taking the distance, you will not have the proper estimator.

Comment: Is 'a' == (mean(Ax), mean(Ay)) ?

Comment: yes, a deterministic (vector) magnitude

Comment: I'm sorry but I am really battling to understand this answer.

Comment: Just take the average of the point, and then take the distance. Do not take distances and then average them. It could be formalized, and proven, but i think you already have it. It is essentially involving saying the average of the squares is different from the square of the average.